# Pushing objects to array in state object. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, closures

I'll start with code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            todo: []
        };
    }

    addTask(newTask) {
        let todo = this.state.todo.slice();
        newTask.id = this.nextId();
        todo.push(newTask);
        this.setState({todo}); //React method to update state object
    }

    //fake id
    nextId() {
        let id = 0;
        this.nextId = () => {
            return ++id;
        };

        return id;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ToDoList list={this.state.todo} />
                <ModalDialog onFormSubmission={this.addTask.bind(this)}/>
                <ActionButton />
            </div>
            );
    }

}
;
```

now I'm expecting that after each call of `addTask(newTask)` -`this.state.todo` array will be populated with another element with unique `id`. So for example:

```
addTask({title: "aa", description: "bb"});
addTask({title: "aa", description: "bb"});
```

should give me:

```
this.state.todo[0].id === 0
this.state.todo[1].id === 1
```

But when I put two objects **with the same values** just like above, this is true:

```
this.state.todo[0].id === 1
this.state.todo[1].id === 1
```

I can't see why. It does work when I push object with unique values.

Comment: it's because React requires you to use `setState` and not directly modify state object

Comment: Not worked with React but this seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/dLbjuLqw/

Comment: After second thought I'm thinking it might has to do something with react...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem:

```
class ToDoForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            description: ''
        };
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.props.onFormSubmission(this.state); //on form submission is `addTask` in this context
        event.preventDefault();
    }    

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
            title: this.refs.title.value,
            description: this.refs.description.value
        });
    }

}
```

correction :

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let {title, description} = this.state;
    this.props.onFormSubmission({title, description});
}
```

I was passing mutable object. I feel dumb :)